# Can you get the validation errors in a functional test

Tags: java, playframework

I want to test that a particular request has validation errors. Is this possible? Something like:

```
assertEquals(true, Validation.hasErrors());
```

This doesn't seem to work.

I've attempted to use:

```
Validation.hasErrors();
Validation.current().hasErrors();
```

Comment: Is it not compiling or return false?

Comment: returning false even though there should be a validation error.

Comment: Since it's returning false, I would double check your test. Maybe post a little to show more context of what's going wrong.

Comment: I've ran it through the debugger. validation.hasErrors() is true in the action. Validation.hasErrors() and Validation.current().hasErrors() are false in the test. I imagine that after the internals of play invoke the action, it clears down validation errors.

Comment: maybe try assertTrue(Validation.hasErrors());

Comment: As i mentioned, Validation.hasErrors() always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this the following:

In my model I have this:

```
@Email
@Required
public String email;
```

Then I can test it with:

```
myobject.email = "bademailbad.com";
Validation v = Validation.current();
v.valid(myobject);
assertEquals(true, v.hasErrors());
```

.. or ..

```
myobject.email = "bademailbad.com";
Validation.valid("email", myobject);
assertEquals(true, Validation.hasErrors());
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: And now I noticed that you where asking about functional tests. >.< My examples should at least work in unit tests. Haven't tried with functional tests.

Comment: I can try this in a functional test, but I doubt it will work since Valdiation.hasErrors() is always false.